# Outlook VSTO - Error while sending appointment from a modal form

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I have a modal form that allows user to make custom selections to generate a message body. The send button on the modal form should save and send the invite. However I get the following error on the line of code that sends the appointment

"Because a modal form is open in outlook, this item cannot be sent"

Is there a way to send the invite without having to change to a non-modal form?

Comment: What code exactly do you use for creating and sending emails?

Comment: I am creating a new outlook appointment, adding body, receipients and then finally invoking appointment.send()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does clicking `Send` close your modal form? Try to close the form first, then call Send.

If not, you can also postpone calling `Send` until your form closes. If the call fails, you can show your form again.

Comment: I tried to close the form before the send. However the form continues to remain open until the code exits from the Form's button click event.  I still get the error.

Comment: Move the code sending the message from the form itself to the code that shows the form: after the call to show the form returns, send the message,

Comment: Let me try it. I will need to find a way to have a shared Boolean variable that will inform the parent code to either send the message or not

Comment: A form's modal result could do that - OK for sending, Cancel for doing nothing.